# How to connect http server for every moment using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Files are uploading to http server then i need to connect to that server need to check if new file is there need to parse that file.please tell me how to connect to http server using c#?and how to check it's new file or old file?

uploaded url like

```
http://uploadfiles.com/upload.php
```

It's not FTP.

Comment: Is the location that the files are uploaded to able to be used as an FTP folder?

Comment: my uploaded url like this "http://uploadfiles.com/upload.php"

Comment: Suggesting that it was FTP was not relevant. I was trying to suggest that you could retrieve them via FTP if that location in which you saved the files was able to be made accessible via FTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something I use in one of my projects for connect to http and download something. upload goes same way

```
public string DLWindowUser(string caption, string caption2, string remote, string local, string user, string password)
        {
            FStatus = new SZOKZZ.FrmStatus();
            FStatus.InitProc(100);
            FStatus.SetCaption(caption, caption2);
            _DlError = null;
            string ret = "";
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                NetworkCredential c = new NetworkCredential();
                c.UserName = user;
                c.Password = password;
                webClient.Credentials = c;
                webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DLDone);
                webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DLSetProc);
                webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(remote), local);
                FStatus.ShowDialog();
                if (_DlError != null)
                    ret = _DlError.Message;
            }
            return ret;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Uploading the files to the server is the first step but downloading them will depend on where this server is storing the files and does it make them accessible through some protocol. For example if the files are stored in a location accessible through the HTTP protocol you could use a [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) to download the contents of a remote url.

For example:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] data = client.DownloadData("http://uploadfiles.com/myfile.txt");
    // TODO: process the data
}
```

You might also checkout the other methods of WebClient such as [`DownloadString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx) and [`DownloadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx). All the methods have asynchronous non-blocking equivalents as well.

Or if it is a XML file that you need to download and parse you could directly use the [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) class:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("http://uploadfiles.com/myfile.xml");
```

Comment: xml files are uploading to server. i need to connect to that server and bring xml file to solution then i need to parse that xml file directly through my code.how to connect to http server and bring xml file ?

Comment: You need to know the URL at which those files are stored. Then use a WebClient as shown in my example to download the file. Once downloaded you could pass it to a `XDocument` to parse it.

Comment: files are uploading continuously how to check it one by one ?

Comment: That will depend on whether and how your web server exposes this information.